# Unable to Access Ubuntu Server Through GUI

Tags: server

I am trying to install Desktop GUI for my Ubuntu Server. I have followed the guide from youtube presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6e0PuU2EHp8

I have installed everything correctly, however when I attempt to connect to https://localhost:8000 Firefox isn't able to establish a connection.

I think this could be an issue with ubuntu internal firewall, but because I'm very new to Unix I wouldn't be able to determine if the problem is firewall related or something else. Basically, when I connect to port 8000 I should get the following webpage:

[image: webpage]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you set up Ajenti like what is pictured in the video?  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-ajenti-control-panel-and-ajenti-v-on-ubuntu-14-04  I have never used the app, so this is all the information that I know.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks for responding. I watched the video again but I didn't see any reference to installing Ajenti. However, I will follow the link you provided

Comment: That is the application that is pictured that runs on port 8000.  There is no default apps installed that run on ports like that.   You need to install them.  One that I used to really like and use was [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) and it runs on port 10000.  Ajenti is something that they setup ahead of time before filming the video.  I wish that authors of videos like that would actually explain the applications that they are using.

Comment: Thanks guys. I also wish authors would explain before publishing video. I have now installed the application and can access through gui

Comment: @Terrance, you answer was correct. I'm not sure how to mark the question answered

Comment: Let me write you one.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu by default does not have any applications setup listening on port 8000.  There are applications that come setup listening like CUPS which is at http://localhost:631 if CUPS is installed at the time.

With the application in the video that is Ajenti (installation steps can be found at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-ajenti-control-panel-and-ajenti-v-on-ubuntu-14-04).   After installing Ajenti then it can be accessed at http://localhost:8000

There are other apps out there for administering to hosts through webpages like [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) which works at http://localhost:10000

Hope this helps!